# Folder Redirection issue (showing warning all the times that it's going to use TEMP profile)

Tags: windows-7, windows-server-2008-r2, folder-redirection

I was playing with Folder Redirection feature of Microsoft.

the only domain controller is under: Windows Server 2008 R2
the workstation is: Windows 7 Enterprise.

I have set GPO, Folder Redirection for Documents only.

Also, I didn't set profile roaming.

Now, when I log in to the Workstation, I see (in Properties) that Redirections are really working. However it's using TEMP profile anyways, even though I set FR only for Documents. not for Desktop nor any other folder I also didn't set up Profile Roaming.

WHy is it showing me this? I am missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copy all the user profile folder from \Users\%UserName% to the new location.

When you set up Folder Redirection in a user that have been already logged on a machine Windows will create the new user folder but it wont have all files that user needs like NTUSER.DAT.

So, If the original folder for that user was created in C:\Users, you have to copy that folder to the new path.